# SwiperJs fade effect

Tags: javascript, slider, laravel-blade, swiper.js

I have a simple slider with SwiperJs, but when I add a fade effect, it still scrolls by default. How can I fix it?

My project uses Laravel Blade, Vite and Swiper 9.4.1 if it matters...

Code:

```
import Swiper from "swiper";

const options = {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  effect: "fade",
  spaceBetween: 16,
  speed: 300,
  loop: true,
  allowTouchMove: false,
};

const slider_1 = new Swiper("#best-sellers-slider-1", options);
const slider_2 = new Swiper("#best-sellers-slider-2", options);
const slider_3 = new Swiper("#best-sellers-slider-3", options);

const nextButton = document.querySelector("#best-seller-next");
const prevButton = document.querySelector("#best-seller-prev");

nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  slider_1.slideNext();
  slider_2.slideNext();
  slider_3.slideNext();
});

prevButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  slider_1.slidePrev();
  slider_2.slidePrev();
  slider_3.slidePrev();
});
```

I'm trying to switch between versions 10.0.4 and 9.4.1. It doesn't help me fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to import the EffectFade module.

```
import Swiper from "swiper";
import { EffectFade } from "swiper/modules";

const options = {
  modules: [ EffectFade ],
  slidesPerView: 1,
  effect: "fade",
  spaceBetween: 16,
  speed: 300,
  loop: true,
  allowTouchMove: false,
};
```